# Rcmdr error: what is this error and how do I fix it?

Tags: r, xquartz

I am currently trying to use the Biodiversity.R package, which requires Rcmdr as a dependancy. I recently updated my Mac to macOS 14.3.1, uninstalled the old version of Xquartz and reinstalled Xquartz v 2.8.5. After restarting my computer and attempting to install in load Rcmdr and load the package I receive the following error.

```
library(Rcmdr)

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘Rcmdr’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Rcmdr', details:
  call: structure(.External(.C_dotTclObjv, objv), class = "tclObj")
  error: [tcl] invalid command name "tk_messageBox".
```

Any solutions to this problem??

Tried reinstalling Xquartz multiple times and restarting system expecting to solve the issue. This did not work.